# RoR - Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, bundle

When I ran `bundle install` this is the output I got:

```
kevindeMacBook-Pro:happy kevin$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    auto-facebook (= 0.4) ruby depends on
      rails (= 4.0.0) ruby

    rails (4.1.1)
```

and I saw other similar problems , can use delete `Gemfile.lock` and `bundle install`.
but I can't found  `Gemfile.lock` this file

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise', '3.0.2'
gem "seo_helper", "~> 1.0.2"
gem "open_graph_helper"

gem "rmagick"
gem "carrierwave"
gem "carrierwave-meta"

gem "settingslogic"

gem "anjlab-bootstrap-rails", "2.3.1.2", :require => "bootstrap-rails"
gem "bootstrap_helper", ">= 4.2.2.1"
gem "simple_form", "~> 3.0.1" 
gem "will_paginate", "3.0.3"
gem "font-awesome-rails", "~> 3.2.1.3"

gem "high_voltage"

gem "airbrake"

gem "rvm-capistrano"

gem "omniauth"
gem "omniauth-facebook"
gem "auto-facebook", "0.4"


gem "whenever"

gem "hipchat"

# Cache
gem "dalli"

gem "compass-rails", "~> 1.1.2"

group :development do
  gem "capistrano"
  gem "capistrano-ext"
  gem "cape"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
  gem "better_errors", "~> 0.9.0"
  gem "magic_encoding"
  gem "annotate"
  gem "powder"
  gem "pry-nav"
  gem "pry-remote"
end
```

Comment: I use the bootstrappers to generate project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
gem "auto-facebook", "0.4"
```

to

```
gem "auto-facebook", "~> 0.42"
```

It looks like 0.4 has the rails version fixed at 4.0.0: https://rubygems.org/gems/auto-facebook/versions/0.4